# Are questions on parliamentary procedure and organization constitutions/bylaws on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, tags

I've recently asked a couple questions [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/25435/when-should-a-constitution-or-bylaws-have-separate-articles-versus-sections-with) and [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/24279/is-there-a-proper-way-to-include-explanatory-text-in-a-constitution). In both cases I wasn't able to find a tag that fit well. If this is the right place for such questions, could a "club-bylaws" tag (or similar) be created?

Answer (score 4):

I do not those those particular questions (the ones you linked to) are appropriate for Law SE, because they are basically about stylistics and not the logical content of law. There has been some sentiment that LSE questions should be about how the government court system deals with a fact, but I think that club rules are amenable to much the same kind of analysis, except that the club can't use a club to enforce its decisions. Interpreting a club rule is not fundamentally different from interpreting a law, *except* that in common law jurisdictions, you also have to know the huge case law history of a particular matter. In principle, *some* questions about by-laws would be appropriate, namely those of the type "what does this mean" or "how would you express". I also think that style questions about statutes are not suitable for Law SE.

A fundamental component of knowledge of law is the ability to read a text and understand what it literally says (and what situations it described), and that skill is applicable to club rules as well. Case and statutory law is mostly irrelevant, unless in some way the club bylaws are themselves illegal (e.g. requiring human sacrifice).

Comment: Is there another place to ask those questions? My intent in asking them is to determine any legal impact that may arise from a change in stylistics. The only real guidance I can find on the internet is "be clear without being overly verbose".